# Pivot Table with All the Index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I am using python pandas to create a pivot table from df. The df looks like:

[image]

The fields that have missing values are: Origin City, Shipment Date, Volume and Landing Date. Note that Landing Date is the sum of Shipment date and TAT.

What I want to get the Output is This:

[image]

I have the following code for the output above:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='Volume', index=['DC'], columns=['Landing date'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value = 0)
```

The actual output I am getting is

[image]

The problem here is my code removes the `DC = DLT` as it has missing value while pivoting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ffill`, what is same as [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`:

```
print (df)
   DC Landing date  Volume
0  MAR     02-09-16    50.0
1  MAR     03-09-16    98.0
2  MAR          NaN     NaN
3  BOY     05-09-16    60.0
4  BOY     06-09-16    14.0
5  DLT          NaN     NaN
6  DLT          NaN     NaN

df['Landing date'] = df['Landing date'].ffill()
print (df)
    DC Landing date  Volume
0  MAR     02-09-16    50.0
1  MAR     03-09-16    98.0
2  MAR     03-09-16     NaN
3  BOY     05-09-16    60.0
4  BOY     06-09-16    14.0
5  DLT     06-09-16     NaN
6  DLT     06-09-16     NaN

df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Volume', index=['DC'], columns=['Landing date'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value = 0)    
df1.index.name = None
df1.columns.name = None
print (df1)
     02-09-16  03-09-16  05-09-16  06-09-16
BOY         0         0        60        14
DLT         0         0         0         0
MAR        50        98         0         0
```

---

You can [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by first non NaN value from column `Landing date`:

```
val = df['Landing date'].dropna().iloc[0]
print (val)
02-09-16

df['Landing date'] = df['Landing date'].fillna(val)
print (df)
    DC Landing date  Volume
0  MAR     02-09-16    50.0
1  MAR     03-09-16    98.0
2  MAR     02-09-16     NaN
3  BOY     05-09-16    60.0
4  BOY     06-09-16    14.0
5  DLT     02-09-16     NaN
6  DLT     02-09-16     NaN
```

Comment: please see the edit.. The actual desired output is the second image. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Only add `df1.columns.name = None`

Comment: jezrael - i need to retain the names of all the DC Column. how can i do this

Comment: You need missing `DLT` row?

Comment: yes ! actually i edited the question just after you posted the ans. can you modify this pls

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Comment: This is perfect. Just a followup question: After using 'ffill'  in the df[Landing date], I see Missing values under Landing date column has been filled with random dates ( 03-09-16 and 06-09-16), but these dates corresponds to some other DCs. Is there any explain for this ?

Comment: They are not random values, but values before NaN. Please check edit. And it works, because my solution only need add some existing values, because `pivot_table` reshape original `DataFrame` and all unique dates from `Landing date` create columns names. So then if values in `Volume` are missing, output rows contain `0` from `fill_value = 0`